# Import keybindings from one OS to another

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, how to import old synced keybindings from one OS to another?

Setting
`"settingsSync.keybindingsPerPlatform": false` in `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
Will make new synced keybindings be shared between every OS;

But what about the old ones?

Synced keybindings are stored in
`~/.config/Code/User/sync/keybindings/lastSynckeybindings.json` in a chaotic and non-human-readable way, and manually editing it is risking to break the file.